# Writing in Call history in android phone

Tags: android, call

I was wondering if there is any way that I can write some numbers into Call History i.e Missed calls.
What I want to do is I want when I run my application it will write a number let say that number is 04556433 in the call history and it will be shown as Missed call alert when I will close the application. Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void insertPlaceholderCall(ContentResolver contentResolver, String number)      {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER, number);
        values.put(CallLog.Calls.DATE, System.currentTimeMillis());
        values.put(CallLog.Calls.DURATION, 0);
        values.put(CallLog.Calls.TYPE, CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE);
        values.put(CallLog.Calls.NEW, 1);
        values.put(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME, "");
        values.put(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NUMBER_TYPE, 0);
        values.put(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NUMBER_LABEL, "");
        contentResolver.insert(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, values);
    }
```

For this you will need the following permission
    `android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS` and `android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS`

Comment: Can we set notifications? I mean to say that through this code I have written number in call log but I want to show notification of Miss call also.

Comment: you can use notification to show a custom notification .. But I am not sure whether you can show the system notificaation for call log